# Read JFrame size from JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a Layout class which extends `JFrame`. Later I am adding `RoadPanel` which extends `JPanel`. At run-time is it possible to know `Layout` frame size in `RoadPanel`?

**Code**

```
class Layout extends JFrame{
    ...Something...
    RoadPanel rp = new RoadPanel();
    this.add(rp);
}

class RoadPanel extends JPanel{
    ...graphics and components...
}
```

Both are implemented in different Class.

---

What I tried so far is to send frame size into the constructor of `RoadPanel`. Yeah, that is so lame as it will send only once while initiated.  :(

How to make this dynamic so it updates continuously?

---

Why I want to do this? It because...

> Purpose of knowing frame size is to scale down my Lines and Arcs of
>   RoadPanel :) But I didn't wanted scale up though. So now I can check
>   if frame size is less than my path.getBounds2D than repaint all line
>   and arc and fit into visible area. But when you increase frame size,
>   RoadPanel drawing should remain same and can be zoomed-in by manually
>   using zoom button.

**Special pointer towards Andrew Thompson's answer, For better practise.**

Comment: Pass the frame itself to the constructor so that you later can query it.

Comment: Good one, But than I am only get "0", while printing frame.getSize();

Comment: That's most probably because the layout manager has not updated the size yet. As Andrew said, your best bet is to let layout managers handle the sizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass the frame itself to the panel constructor and later query the size, or you might use `getParent()` which should return the direct parent of the panel. In that case it might be necessary to move further up the hierarchy until you reach the frame.

Edit: depending on what you want to achieve, I'd suggest you first try and use Andrew's suggestions and use layout managers. You should use the parent's size directly only *if* the layout manager doens't provide the functionality you need (note that the way that functionality is provided might be different than what you expect).

Answer (score 4):

> ..is it possible to know Layout frame size in RoadPanel?

Use a layout (or layouts).  Then it won't be necessary to know the size of the parent container.

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for details.

#### Update 1

> How to make this dynamic so it updates continuously?

The layouts will update the sizes and positions of components automatically.  For custom painting, simply call `Container.getSize()` at time of `paintComponent()`.

#### Update 2

> However purpose of knowing frame size is to scale down my Lines and Arcs of RoadPanel

In case I was not clear enough above: **For custom painting, simply call `Container.getSize()` at time of `paintComponent()`.**  In this instance, the `Container` would be `RoadPanel`.  Incidentally, this will work correctly irrespective of:

- `RoadPanel` having a `Border`.
- Not being in a `Frame` or not being the root component.

Comment: Correct, However purpose of knowing frame size is to scale down my Lines and Arcs of RoadPanel :) But I didn't wanted scale up though. So now I can check if frame size is less than my path.getBounds2D than repaint all arc and fit into visible area. But when you scale up it should remain same and can be zoomed in by manually using zoom button :)

Comment: @mKorbel, Could you please tell me a LayoutManager, That can save me this extra coding?

Answer (score 1):

From `RoadPanel` try:

```
this.getParent().getSize();
```

Comment: +1, Thanks perfectly, What I wanted accepting Thomas's answer as he wrote it first lol :)